# How can I test whether my cloud chamber is supersaturated or not?

Tags: thermodynamics, particle-physics, experimental-physics, experimental-technology

Me and my friend are building a diffusion cloud chamber for a school project. In stead of using dry ice or a peltier, we have used the phase changer of a freezer to cool our plate. We were able to cool our plate down to -35.8° C. The top of our chamber was heated to 9.6° C, and the distance between the top and bottom of our chamber measures approximately 15 cm. We provided our chamber with 99% pure isopropanol, but unfortunately no trails showed up. We did not even saw cloud formation or precipitation, just pools of isopropanol forming on the bottom.

At first, we thought the temperature was not low enough to supersaturate the air with isopropanol. We decided to test this by polluting the air in the chamber with charcoal. The charcoal-dustparticles would act as seeds for vapor to condense around just like ionised tracks were supposed to do. To our surprise, we found that charcoal did cause cloud formation and precipitation. Can we now conclude that our chamber was indeed in a supersaturated state, and that the temperature is not the problem?

If temperature is in fact the limiting factor, obviously we have to try to lower it further. However, might it be an idea to cool the air quicker by decreasing the height whilst maintaining the temperature gradient? Or might there be an other way (besides pressure) to quickly decrease the vapor capacity of air?

Apologies for the length of my question(s). Any input is much appreciated!

**Edit:** To clarify my question, does the air have to be supersaturated for clouds to form around dust particles? In order to see ion-tracks, the air does have to supersaturated. However, dust particles are way bigger, so is it right to pull the conclusion that the chamber is supersaturated when clouds form around dust particles?

Comment: Try testing with an alpha source, thoriated welding rod might be easiest to obtain for you.

Comment: Another alpha source easily available is the button from a spent smoke detector containing the oxide of americium 241. Picture here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Americium-241

Comment: Also you may not need to heat the top. Is that where your reservoir of isopropanol is? I have an old Fischer Scientific cloud chamber. Its instructions call for soaking a sponge on the top plate and placing a pool of alcohol on the bottom plate. Using dry ice I've been able to see condensation trails from various alpha emitting radoisotopes. And occasionally a cosmic ray. Without the carbon have you seen rain? You may observe waves of rain that indicate the chamber's near supersaturated state. Also important that you have no leaks or internal drafts.

Comment: Related? http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/281297/104696

Comment: Please do not suggest that people take smoke detectors apart for the radioactive material therein: no particular effort has been made to insure that such sources are safe in ordinary handling because you aren't suppose to handle them. Commercial off the shelf needle source are inexpensive don't require paperwork (at least in the US) and are designed to be safe to handle. If you want higher rates and gammas too, then getting a piece of vintage Fiestaware (with the uranium glaze) is pretty safe as the radio-nucleides are all glassified in the glaze.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies! Unfortunately, radioactive isotopes are very hard to come by in the Netherlands. Ols smoke detectors are very rare here. Maybe, i could find them in Belgium.

Comment: @dmckee, I was wondering whether fiestaware would work because alpha and beta radiation is easily blocked out by dense material. Would it be an idea to crush it into a powder?

Comment: Don't do that! That would defete the purpose of containing the material. Relatively few of the alphas get out, but both gamma and beta should show tracks in your chamber as well. And the rate is pretty high. My salt shaker counts about 400 Bq at 5 cm with a small Geiger counter.

Comment: @doscience, we made sure our chamber was airtight and using a feather, we have concluded that there was no internal draft. Yes, our isopropanol reservoir is located on top, not heating it does not seem to lower the bottom temperature, the top just gets colder. So it seemed logical to heat the top so that the air's vapor capacity increases. It seemed to me that this would make it easier to supersaturate. Without carbon, no fog or rain...

Comment: Are you doing the experiment in the basement? you may be losing the cosmics.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xky3f1aSkB8

Comment: @anna v, We are testing the chamber in a garage, under a plexiglass window. Although our city lies under sea level, a dry ice chamber does show tracks. So that should not be an issue...

Comment: just to note that sea level makes no difference. It is intervening mass on top that does. Since you are in the open (little mass on top of garage)and the only difference is the dry ice, I would check the thermometer (calibrate it) and the placing of the cooler with respect to the chamber, is it a good radiator/ absorber ? i.e. metal?