# Cloud Chamber not showing

Tags: experimental-physics, radiation, cosmic-rays

I am trying to build a thermoelectric cloud chamber, it’s not showing any trails with a alpha source or cosmic rays. The only thing I see is alcohol vapour (small white dots). Using 99% isopropyl alcohol and temperature of plate up around -33C. Electric field is around 800v.

Here are some photos, thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! Please note that a bunch of photos without any accompanying explanation and without any more question than "help me" do not constitute a specific physics question, which is what this site is for.

Comment: @ACuriousMind It is difficult to be more specific than this when things do not work. It is also difficult to answer such problems, but that is a different issue. And there might be people here with experience of such a setup. I see a general unfriendliness here to experimental questions: "go ask on chemistry", "go ask on engineering", etc.

Comment: @freddieknets is an expert on this, see his answer at https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/281297/